# Use keywords in class to call a specific method

Tags: python, class, methods, keyword

Suppose a Python class has different methods, and depending on what the user specifies, a different method is carried out in the main function `calculate()`.

In the example below the user needs to specify the  keyword argument `'methodOne'` or `'methodTwo'`. If no or an incorrect keyword is specified it should default to `'methodOne'`.

```
class someClass(object):
    def __init__(self,method=None):
        methodList = ['methodOne','methodTwo']
        if method in methodList:
            self.chosenMethod = method
        else:
            self.chosenMethod = self.methodOne

    def methodOne(self):
        return 1

    def methodTwo(self):
        return 2

    def calculate(self):
        return self.chosenMethod()
```

The above clearly does not work since `method` is a string and not a function. How can I select `self.methedOne()` or `self.methedOne()` based on my keyword argument `method`? In principle the following works:

```
def __init__(self,method=None):
    if method == 'methodOne':
        self.chosenMethod = self.methodOne
    elif method == 'methodTwo':
        self.chosenMethod = self.methodTwo
    else:
        self.chosenMethod = self.methodOne
```

But if I have more than two methods this becomes rather ugly. Is there a way to do this similar to my original code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python

Comment: The answers below already show the use of `getattr`. That approach is called reflection (or introspection): code that is inspecting its own structure. However, keep in mind that if `method` is a user-provided value, you'd do well to verify that it refers to one of the intended methods. After all, a user could enter `'calculate'`, or `'__class__'`, or the name of a non-callable attribute, causing all kinds of problems (and maybe even security risks, depending on context).

Comment: @PieterWitvoet The `if method in methodList` clause should prevent that.

Comment: @Forzaa: Very well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) for that purpose:

```
class someClass(object):
    def __init__(self,method=None):
        methodList = ['methodOne','methodTwo']
        if method in methodList:
            self.chosenMethod = method
        else:
            self.chosenMethod = self.methodOne

    def methodOne(self):
        return 1

    def methodTwo(self):
        return 2

    def calculate(self):
        return getattr(self, self.chosenMethod)()

x = someClass(method='methodOne')
print x.calculate()
>>> 1
```

Comment: Well, two almost identical answers at the same time. Guess this is the way then :). I'll accept yours since it is more in line with my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the actual method on the class object.

```
class someClass(object):
    def __init__(self,method=None):
        # store it with the object so we can access it later in calculate method
        self.method = method

    def methodOne(self):
        return 1

    def methodTwo(self):
        return 2

    def calculate(self):
        # get the actual method from the string here
        # if no such method exists then use methodOne instead
        return getattr(self, self.method, self.methodOne)()


> someClass('methodOne').calculate()
# 1

> someClass('methodTwo').calculate()
# 2
```

Comment: For the handling of the default case you could add `getattr(self, self.method, self.methodOne)()`